# How to define destination device stream in cudaMemcpyPeerAsync()?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am doing a asynchronous memcpy from gpu0 to gpu1 using cudaMemcpyPeerAsync().

cudaMemcpyAsync() provides option for stream to use for gpu0, but not for gpu1. Can I somehow define the stream of the receiving device too?

I am using OpenMP threads to manage each of the devices (so, they are in separate context).

Visual Profiler shows the stream for sending device but for receiving device, this memcpy is just shown in the MemCpy (PtoP) and not in any of the streams (not even in the default stream)

PS: My current implementation works fine. I just want to overlap the sending and receiving communication.

Comment: To define the destination stream also, you should have some sort of synchronization between streams in separate GPUs, which I do not think is possible and would be contradictory with the "async" nature of the API. Perhaps you would achieve overlap between sending and receiving communications depending on the GPUs you are using, and in particular if they have two copy engines.

Comment: Hi Jack. Thanks for your reply.
Yes, they do have two copy engines (I'm using 4 K10 GPUs). 
While surfing around, I found that event/stream of one GPU can be queried from another GPU.
Trying to implement that, will come back with results.

Comment: What does "I just want to overlap the sending and receiving communication" mean in this context? What is sending and what is receiving, and how can they overlap?

Comment: @talonmies: Since NVIDIA GK104 has dual memory copy engines (ie, it can send and receive data simultaneously), so I wanted to overlap both.
eg. gpu0 sends data to gpu1 and at the same time receives data from another gpu (say gpu2).

Answer (score 1):

There is no API call for a cuda peer copy that allows you to specify streams on both ends.  The simple answer to your question is no.

Streams are a way of organizing activity.  The cudaMemcpyPeerAsync call will show up in the stream (and device) to which it is assigned.  This is the level of control you have with the API.

Since streams dictate (i.e. control, regulate) behavior, being able to assign a cuda task to separate streams (on more than one device, in this case) is a level of control that is not exposed in CUDA.  Devices (and streams) are intended to operate asynchronously, and requiring that a particular cuda task satisfy the requirements of two separate streams, (on two separate devices in this case) would introduce a type of synchronization that is not appropriate, and could lead to various kinds of activity stalls, and perhaps even deadlock.

None of the description here, nor the behavior of cudaMemcpyPeerAsync, should prevent you from overlapping copy operations in various directions.  In fact, in my opinion, assigning a cuda task to more than one stream would make flexible overlap more difficult to achieve.

If you have difficulty achieving a particular overlap, you should probably describe the problem (i.e., provide a simple reproducer complete compilable SSCCE.org code), and show the current overlap scenario that visual profiler shows, and describe the desired overlap scenario.