# What is the difference between cudaMemcpy() and cudaMemcpyPeer() for P2P-copy?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I want to copy data from GPU0-DDR to GPU1-DDR directly without CPU-RAM.

As said here on the page-15: http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/cuda/MultiGPU_Programming.pdf

```
Peer-to-Peer Memcpy
 Direct copy from pointer on GPU A to pointer on GPU B

 With UVA, just use cudaMemcpy(…, cudaMemcpyDefault)
     Or cudaMemcpyAsync(…, cudaMemcpyDefault)

 Also non-UVA explicit P2P copies:
     cudaError_t cudaMemcpyPeer( void * dst, int dstDevice, const void* src, 
        int srcDevice, size_t count )
     cudaError_t cudaMemcpyPeerAsync( void * dst, int dstDevice,
        const void* src, int srcDevice, size_t count, cuda_stream_t stream = 0 )
```

1. If I use **[`cudaMemcpy()`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741.html#g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741)** then do I must at first to set a flag `cudaSetDeviceFlags( cudaDeviceMapHost )`?
2. Do I have to use `cudaMemcpy()` pointers which I got as result from the function `cudaHostGetDevicePointer(& uva_ptr, ptr, 0)`?
3. Are there any advantages of function **[`cudaMemcpyPeer()`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g046702971bc5a66d9bc6000682a6d844.html#g046702971bc5a66d9bc6000682a6d844)**, and if no any advantage, why it is needed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unified Virtual Addressing (UVA) enables one address space for all CPU and GPU memories since it allows determining physical memory location from pointer value.

**Peer-to-peer memcpy with UVA***

When UVA is possible, then `cudaMemcpy` can be used for peer-to-peer `memcpy` since CUDA can infer which device "owns" which memory. The instructions you typically need to perform a peer-to-peer `memcpy` with UVA are the following:

```
//Check for peer access between participating GPUs: 
cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer(&can_access_peer_0_1, gpuid_0, gpuid_1);
cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer(&can_access_peer_1_0, gpuid_1, gpuid_0);

//Enable peer access between participating GPUs:
cudaSetDevice(gpuid_0);
cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(gpuid_1, 0);
cudaSetDevice(gpuid_1);
cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(gpuid_0, 0);

//UVA memory copy:
cudaMemcpy(gpu0_buf, gpu1_buf, buf_size, cudaMemcpyDefault);
```

**Peer-to-peer memcpy without UVA**

When UVA is not possible, then peer-to-peer memcpy is done via `cudaMemcpyPeer`. Here is an example

```
// Set device 0 as current
cudaSetDevice(0); 
float* p0;
size_t size = 1024 * sizeof(float);
// Allocate memory on device 0
cudaMalloc(&p0, size); 
// Set device 1 as current
cudaSetDevice(1); 
float* p1;
// Allocate memory on device 1
cudaMalloc(&p1, size); 
// Set device 0 as current
cudaSetDevice(0);
// Launch kernel on device 0
MyKernel<<<1000, 128>>>(p0); 
// Set device 1 as current
cudaSetDevice(1); 
// Copy p0 to p1
cudaMemcpyPeer(p1, 1, p0, 0, size); 
// Launch kernel on device 1
MyKernel<<<1000, 128>>>(p1);
```

As you can see, while in the former case (UVA possible) you don't need to specify which device the different pointers refer to, in the latter case (UVA not possible) you have to explicitly mention which device the pointers refer to.

The instruction

```
cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);
```

is used to enable host mapping to device memory, which is a different thing and regards host<->device memory movements and not peer-to-peer memory movements, which is the topic of your post.

In conclusion, the answer to your questions are:

1. NO;
2. NO;
3. When possible, enable UVA and use `cudaMemcpy` (you don't need to specify the devices); otherwise, use `cudaMemcpyPeer` (and you need to specify the devices).

Comment: Thanks! But in which context (`setCudaDevice(0 or 1);`) do I must to be before launch `cudaMemcpyPeer(p1, 1, p0, 0, size);`, in 0 or 1?

Comment: @Alex I don't think it is relevant since you specify source and destination devices in the call to `cudaMemcpyPeer`.

Comment: Thanks. But if I use `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(,,,,stream);` then do I must to set the context by using `setCudaDevice();` in which this stream was created?

Comment: @Alex I don't think you need to specify the device also in this case. From the answer to [How to define destination device stream in cudaMemcpyPeerAsync()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940831/how-to-define-destination-device-stream-in-cudamemcpypeerasync), it is explicitly written that _the `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync` call will show up in the stream (and device) to which it is assigned_ and, in particular, to the source device. See also the example on slide 20 of [Multi-GPU Programming](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/116711/sc11-multi-gpu.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! But as said here, if I use stream in context (in example 1) which created in different context (in example 0), then I will get an error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443693/is-there-a-relationship-between-on-which-of-devices-was-created-stream-and-on-wh?noredirect=1#comment34143195_22443693

Comment: @Alex You have to see things the other way around. You _have_ to ensure that the `stream` you are using as an argument to `cudaMemcpypeerAsync` has been created on the source device of the peer-to-peer asynchronous memory transfer.

Comment: Do you mean that the current context matters only for `__global__ kernel_function()`, not for `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync()`? And for `cudaMemcpyAsync()` and `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync()` is only important that stream has been created for the device from (source pointer) which the data is copied, isn't it?

Comment: @Alex I have provided an answer to your new question: [What device number should I use (0 or 1), to copy P2P (GPU0->GPU1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736159/what-device-number-should-i-use-0-or-1-to-copy-p2p-gpu0-gpu1/22792494#22792494). My above comment is incorrect due to a misprint. It should read as "You have to ensure that the `stream` you are using as an argument to `cudaMemcpypeerAsync` has been created for the device set by the last `cudaSetDevice`." You can either use a `stream` created for the source or for the destination device.

Comment: @JackOLantern: Why do we need the `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer` checks in the UVA case, but not in the non-UVA case?