# What device number should I use (0 or 1), to copy P2P (GPU0->GPU1)?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

What number of device do I must to set 0 or 1 in `cudaSetDevice();`, to copy P2P (GPU0->GPU1) by using `cudaStreamCreate(stream); cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(p1, 1, p0, 0, size, stream);` ?

Code:

```
// Set device 0 as current
cudaSetDevice(0); 
float* p0;
size_t size = 1024 * sizeof(float);
// Allocate memory on device 0
cudaMalloc(&p0, size); 
// Set device 1 as current
cudaSetDevice(1); 
float* p1;
// Allocate memory on device 1
cudaMalloc(&p1, size); 
// Set device 0 as current
cudaSetDevice(0);
// Launch kernel on device 0
MyKernel<<<1000, 128>>>(p0); 

// What number do I must to set 0 or 1?
cudaSetDevice(1); // cudaSetDevice(0); 
cudaStream_t stream;
cudaStreamCreate(stream);

// Copy p0 to p1
cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(p1, 1, p0, 0, size, stream); 
cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);

// Launch kernel on device 1
cudaSetDevice(1); 
MyKernel<<<1000, 128>>>(p1);
```

**UPDATE 31.03.2014:**
Or does the current context important only for `__global__ kernel_function()`, not for `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync()`? And for `cudaMemcpyAsync()` and `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync()` is only important that stream has been created for the device from (source pointer) which the data is copied, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think it matters. You set both the `srcDevice` and `destDevice` in the function arguments, so there is no ambiguity as to which device context to operate in.

Comment: I think this point has been already discussed in [What is the difference between cudaMemcpy() and cudaMemcpyPeer() for P2P-copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694518/what-is-the-difference-between-cudamemcpy-and-cudamemcpypeer-for-p2p-copy/22699912?noredirect=1#comment34654114_22699912) following an explicit comment by the OP.

Comment: @JackOLantern You said that "I do not need to specify the device also in this case." But as said here, if I use stream in context (in example 1) which created in different context (in example 0), then I will get an error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22444170/1558037

Comment: @Alex You have to see things the other way around. For the reason you are mentioning, you have to ensure that the `stream` you are using as an argument to the `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync` call has been created for the device which is the source of the transfer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the call to [cudaMemcpyPeerAsync](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g8ff91443cbf4bb9334bec897ac7d6691.html) you can specify a non-default `stream`. So your first question is: *which device should I set by `cudaSetDevice` before the call to `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync`?*

The answer is that you have to set, by `cudaSetDevice`, the device for which the `stream` has been created. You can **either use a `stream` created for the source or for the destination device**. Although, at the best of my knowledge, not explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g8ff91443cbf4bb9334bec897ac7d6691.html), this possibility can be inferred by Robert Crovella's answer to [How to define destination device stream in cudaMemcpyPeerAsync()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940831/how-to-define-destination-device-stream-in-cudamemcpypeerasync). Please, note that, as of 2011 and according to [Multi-GPU Programming](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/116711/sc11-multi-gpu.pdf), performance is maximized when `stream` belongs to the source GPU.

Let me recall some important points when using `streams` in the framework of multi-GPU, borrowed from [Multi-GPU Programming](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/cuda_webinars_multi_gpu.pdf), and which support the above statements:

1. CUDA `streams` are *per device*;
2. `streams` are determined by the GPU that was current at the time of their creation;
3. Calls to a `stream` can be issued only when its device is current.