# Why cudaMemcpyAsync P2P copy is not happening in the specified stream

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

As is pointed out in the answer in the answer to this question

[What device number should I use (0 or 1), to copy P2P (GPU0->GPU1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736159/what-device-number-should-i-use-0-or-1-to-copy-p2p-gpu0-gpu1)

Either cuda stream on the source or the destination GPU can be used for peer to peer copy. However, here's what I got from profiling, it is a bit confusing.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

int main() {
  cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(0, 1);
  cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(1, 0);

  // on device 0
  cudaSetDevice(0);
  float* data0;
  cudaMalloc(&data0, 1024000);

  // on device 1
  cudaSetDevice(1);
  cudaStream_t stream1;
  cudaStreamCreate(&stream1);
  float* data1;
  cudaMalloc(&data1, 1024000);

  cudaMemcpyAsync(data0, data1, 1024000, cudaMemcpyDefault, stream1);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaMemcpyAsync(data1, data0, 1024000, cudaMemcpyDefault, stream1);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

[image]

Question is,

Why are the copy jobs executed on device 0 when I explicitly assign it to device 1?

Comment: I can certainly try to help, but it looks like you've asked about 5 different questions here.  The question in the title is easy to answer, but it seems like you're looking for a treatise on the topic.  Asking multiple questions in a single SO question is not a good idea, it makes the question considerably more difficult to answer.  If you want help, I suggest asking one focused question.  Have you read [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736159/what-device-number-should-i-use-0-or-1-to-copy-p2p-gpu0-gpu1) ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for pointing out, I've checked the link you suggested, and refined my question.

Comment: I concur with the prior feedback. Please consider updating your "question" text so that it is worded as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is really careless!

[`cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__PEER_g9e5ea65a18938c2b8715a5602105c306.html#g9e5ea65a18938c2b8715a5602105c306) does not accept two device ids, the second argument should always be 0.

After `cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess` is called correctly, the profiling result shows that `cudaMemcpyAsync` always happens in the source device no matter which stream is set. It seems if a stream in the destination GPU is used, it will be reallocated to a stream in the source device, which is created automatically.

However, although copy is always executed in the source device, if the function is issued to the destination stream, it will block the destination stream until the copy finishes, I guess it is through `cudaEvent`. And I guess that's why

> "performance is maximized when stream belongs to the source GPU." as stated in this post
>   [What device number should I use (0 or 1), to copy P2P (GPU0->GPU1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736159/what-device-number-should-i-use-0-or-1-to-copy-p2p-gpu0-gpu1)

For example:

```
cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(data0, 0, data1, 1, 1024000, stream0);
cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(data1, 1, data0, 0, 1024000, stream0);
```

Although the first copy will be assigned to device 0 and second to device 1, this two operation will not overlap, because they are in the same stream.

If the first copy is set to device 1, then they can overlap.

```
cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(data0, 0, data1, 1, 1024000, stream1);
cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(data1, 1, data0, 0, 1024000, stream0);
```

Answer (score 3):

The indexing scheme in the profiler is different from the indexing used by the cudaSetDevice function. If you look at your code, the stream you created is made on device 1 but it is associated with device indexed [0] on the profiler. You should use the [NVTX's Resource Naming API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvtx-naming%20NVTX%20Resource%20Naming%20API) to name the device. It will give you a better idea of how the resources are mapped on the profiler.

Comment: This seem to be the answer given the question I asked here. But if you saw the previous version of the question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29226727/revisions you'll see that it is not the case. The figure showed that no matter which device I put the copy operation, the profile result always shows them on device 0.